# Why its stuck on "Validating" in Unity Hub?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The problem I have with Unity Hub is that when I installed Android Build Support, the Validating loading took forever. I have this problem already stuck and when I install it every time it is stuck on Validating, and I don’t know what to do.

I also talked to other people but they also do not understand what the problem is. At first this problem was with Android Build Support and now with the Unity Editor installation itself (2022.3.8f1).

[image]

I tried reinstalling Unity Editor and Unity Hub but this problem also appeared when I started installing Unity Editor (2022.3.8f1) again.

I also tried to find answers on YouTube, but this also did not help and no one talked about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, go to `C:/Users/[you]/AppData/Roaming/UnityHub/Logs/`, and you can see log files which might contain an error message (assuming that the approach of 'giving it plenty of time to validate' didn't work). However, looking at the response to [a similar question on the Unity Q&A website](https://discussions.unity.com/t/i-am-just-install-unity-hub-but-editor-application-is-still-validating-what-should-i-do/265484), you could try [reporting it as a bug](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206336985-How-do-I-submit-a-bug-report-#h_01FMMCVHSQCSX4DBCSB3FXP9FS)

Comment: @11belowstudio There is nothing in the logs, I don’t understand how to fix it. One person had this problem and wrote the following: "I found the problem, my install location and download location were set under different parent folders so the installer was not able to access the install location. I just set both to the same folder and it works edit: you will still need to go the download folder location and install manually" but I don't understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quit your Unity Hub & run it with administrator
2. Go to Preferences => Install and make sure that Installs locations & Downloads location are the same

[image: Edit this]

Comment: I did this disabled all antivirus and ran the program as System Admin, it refuses to install the Linux target modules for me.